# How to use "Chapter One" instead of "Chapter 1" when referring to it in the main text

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, chapters, labels

I want to use "chapter one" instead of "chapter 1" when I refer to a chapter inside the text. When I use `\ref{ch:label}` it just returns the chapter number, and when I use `\autoref{ch:label}` it will return "Chapter 1".

What should I do to get "Chapter One" instead of "Chapter 1"?

Comment: you still want "1" not "One" in the chapter heading?

Comment: I want "one" in both not 1.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just define `\thechapter` as required:

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\ifcase\value{chapter}\or One\or Two\or Three\else Many\fi}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Aaa\label{this}}

xxxx \ref{this}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that  quite easily with the `fmtcount` package:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fmtcount}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Aaa\label{firstlbl}}
    \lipsum[11]

    xxxx Chapter \ref{firstlbl}

    \end{document}
```

[image]